# Django where to put the shared models and logic

Tags: python, django, conventions

I Have the following folder setup:

- myproject
- web
- worker

The web project is a website containing the typical django setup and all, including the model and some service classes which move the logic away from the views. The website will display data coming from a database. The worker folder contains 2 classes which are filling the database and aggregate it. These 2 classes are like background processes. My question is, how should I structure this?

- Should each worker class get his own application folder
- If so, I would prefer to move the models out of the web project in the myproject folder, since they are shared between the applications. However this seems to be against the django convention, why so? And how would the convention handle this?
- If not, where should I put these worker processes? And how should I run them ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a really broad question. Project organization is going to vary project to project. You need to keep your models in an "app" directory so that Django handles any migrations. If there's no table for the class, put it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if I have stuff to be shared between different sections I either:
1) make a lib and install it via pip
2) make a helper folder within the project

Comment: Yeah thats my point, I share just the models. Not the rest of the web priject so i want to move them to a lib folder but that is against django conventions

Comment: That's not against the django conventions, wrapping that in a lib does not violate DRY so to me it seems very right

Answer (score 0):

Keep the project and the app(s) separate and create proper Python packages to handle dependencies. I.e.

```
src/sites/web   <-- the project, containing manage.py, settings and root urls
```

and

```
src/apps/myapp  <-- the app, containing models, views, etc
src/apps/myapp/worker  <-- strongly related functionality
```

in `src/sites/web/setup.py` (and/or `requirements.txt`) you would add `myapp` as an (install) dependency.

If `worker` is only loosely related functionality, then a separate package would make sense, e.g.:

```
src/lib/worker
```

where `src/lib/worker/setup.py` (and/or `requirements.txt`) would add `myapp` as a dependency, and `src/sites/web/setup.py` would add `worker` as a dependency.